# Rumbling noise when going slow or stopped

Tags: chevrolet, noise, cobalt

Just some preliminary information on the car:

- Chevrolet Cobalt 2005
- 260k km milage
- supposedly the engine was 'rebuilt' after 160k

**The problem:**

A rumbling noise (rough noise, much like an motorcycle sound) eminates from the car [generally] when stopped. It vibrates the car as well.

It occurs in several different ways, usually depending on what you do first:

1. If the car is already running and you have been in motion, it almost always makes the sound when sitting idle in drive with the foot on the brake. If the brake is released and the car is allowed to roll forward, it disappears slightly, and if the gas is pressed it disappears similarly. If the car is put into neutral in this case, it completely stops as well, with a abrupt 'kachunk' sound.
2. Sometimes, when slowing down the car from a fast speed, it makes the noise, though it is not known to have any correlation with the brake.
3. When the car was parked, if the car is shifted into drive, it sometimes makes the sound then as well.

Does anyone have any clue what this might be? Thanks in advance!